# Навигация по лэндингу

Tags: javascript

Может кто сталкивался с этим? 
Когда скролю, то булет увеличивается и немного уходит в сторону из-за того, что становится больше.

Как это исправить ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужно исправлять стили, чтобы не уходил

Comment: @Grundy, КО не дремлет?

Comment: Покажите Ваши стили что ли, без них тассеографией заниматься лень.

Comment: Есть много вариантов, код в студию...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/teue9ctu/
Вот. Класс active прыгает,в зависимости от того, на каком слайде я нахожусь

Comment: Вопрос решен. Додумался.Спасибо